# Multiple values in Dialog box

Tags: java, swing

i am trying to learn how to input multiple input in dialog box

For E.G The below program ask the user to enter the value of x 1 , Y 1 and radius in separate boxes  , What would look nice is if the user can Enter the Value X ,Y and radius in the same box .. Please let me know

```
[code]
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class C3E29GeometryTwoCircles 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // Ask the user to enter the x1 coordinate.
        String strNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the value of x1 coordinate " );
        double x1 = Double.parseDouble(strNumber);

        strNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the value of y1 coordinate  " );
        double y1 = Double.parseDouble(strNumber);

        strNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the value of radius " );
        double r1 = Double.parseDouble(strNumber);

        strNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the value of x2 coordinate " );
        double x2 = Double.parseDouble(strNumber);

        strNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the value of y2 coordinate  " );
        double y2 = Double.parseDouble(strNumber);

        strNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the value of radius " );
        double r2 = Double.parseDouble(strNumber);

        double distance = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2)));   

        String strOutput;
        if ((distance <= Math.abs(r1 - r2))) 
        {  

           strOutput = "The circle2 is inside circle1 ";
        }
        else if (distance <= (r1 + r2)) 
        {  

           strOutput = "circle2 overlaps circle1";  
        }
        else 
        {  
            strOutput = "circle2 does not overlap circle1";   
        }  
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, strOutput);
    }
}
[/code]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do everything with dialogs I assume you havent gotten into the swing library yet, in which case the, probably, easiest solution is to split the input from the dialogs.
Tell the users to enter the values in a certain order and seperate them with comma, space, etc. then you split the string on that character.

```
String strNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the value of x,y and radius, separated by space." );
String[] input = strNumber.split(" ");
double x1 = Double.parseDouble(input[0]);
double y1 = Double.parseDouble(input[1]);
double r1 = Double.parseDouble(input[2]);
```

Edit: You would ofc need to check/validate your input, to avoid NumberFormatException and ArrayIndexOutOfBounds.